# How to print a value as a variable from a cell in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

For

```
A=[1;3;5]
```

and

```
B=cell(7,1)
```

I have the following results stored in a cell

```
[1]
[3]
[5]
[1;3]
[1;5]
[3;5]
[1;3;5]
```

I would like to `print` the results in a way that `a=1`, `b=3`, and `c=5`. -- Basically assign each value in A to a variable.

How would I do this in Matlab ?

---

I am looking for a result which can be something like this :

```
" you can have a "
" you can have b "
" you can have c "
" you can have a or b "
.
.
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `C` be the array of letters you want to assign to the numbers in `A`. Then

```
A = [1 3 5];
B = {[1]; [3]; [5]; [1;3]; [1;5]; [3;5]; [1;3;5]};
C = ['a', 'b', 'c']

k = 6; % indicates current line of B
str = ['you can have ' strrep(strrep(sprintf('_%c_', ...
    C(ismember(A, B{k}))'), '__', ' or '), '_', '')];
```

results in

```
str =

you can have a or b or c
```

If you want to **create the responses to all fields in** `B` **at once**, you can use

```
allStr = arrayfun(@(x) ['you can have ' strrep(strrep(sprintf('_%c_', ...
    C(ismember(A, B{x}))'), '__', ' or '), '_', '')], ...
    (1:length(B))', 'uniformoutput', false)
```

This results in

```
allStr = 

    'you can have a'
    'you can have b'
    'you can have c'
    'you can have a or b'
    'you can have a or c'
    'you can have b or c'
    'you can have a or b or c'
```

**A step by step explanation of this code** is as follows:

```
% which contents of A can be found in B?
idx = ismember(A, B{k})'; 

% to which letters do these indices correspond?
letters = C(idx);

% group the letters in a string embedded in '_' as place holders for later use
% by this, the places between letters will be marked with '__' and the places 
% at the beginning and the end of the string will be marked with '_'
stringRaw = sprintf('_%c_', letters); 

% replace each occurrence of '__' by ' or '
stringOr = strrep(stringRaw, '__', ' or ');

% replace each occurrence of '_' by ''
stringClean = strrep(stringOr, '_', ''); 

% add first half of sentence
stringComplete = ['you can have ' stringClean];
```

**To get this working with complete words** (as requested in the comments), you need to transform `C` into a cell array of strings and update the formula accordingly:

```
A = [1 3 5];
B = {[1]; [3]; [5]; [1;3]; [1;5]; [3;5]; [1;3;5]};
C = {'first', 'second', 'third'}

k = 7; % indicates current line of B
str = ['you can have ' strrep(strrep(sprintf('_%s_', ...
    C{ismember(A, B{k})}), '__', ' or '), '_', '')];
```

This results in:

```
str =

you can have first or second or third
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code ? I don't really understand what's going on and would love to learn how it works.

Comment: Thank you that makes a bit more sense .. What does `arrayfun(@x .. )` stand for ? what's the use of `@x` ? Also for second code, last part, you have `(1:length(B))', 'uniformoutput', false)` .. what does that mean ?

Comment: Furthermore, how can I change the name to something else ? Instead of one variable `a`, if I change it to `first` then `a b c` will be replaced with `f i r`. How can I fix this ? I replaced `%c` with a `%s` but that didn't work. Thank you for answering, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Concerning `arrayfun`, please see http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html. The second question I cannot answer right now I do not have access to matlab. Hint: Try transforming `C` to a cell array and update the other formulas accordingly.

Comment: I opened a new question regarding printing these as strings, as the answer you gave me is perfect to print as variables.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood properly, you want something like this:

```
numToLetter = [ 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c' ];
B = { 1, 3, 5, [ 1; 3 ], [ 1; 5 ], [ 3; 5 ], [ 1; 3; 5 ] };

% Loop though each entry in our cell array
for i = 1 : length(B)

  fprintf(' you can have ');               % Print initial message

  % Loop though each vector element inside the B{i}
  for j = 1 : length(B{i})
    fprintf('%c', numToLetter(B{i}(j) ) )  % Use our numToLetter lookup table
                                           % to convert the number to a letter,
                                           % and print it out.

    if j ~= length(B{i})
      fprintf(' or ');                     % Print 'or' if there are more to come
    end
  end
  fprintf('\n');                           % New line
end
```

The main bit of your question was how to assign each number to a letter (note: I know you asked to assign each one to a variable, but I don't think that's quite what you want.).  This is done using a lookup table, called `numToLetter`, which has `a` stored at `1`, `b` stored at `3`, and `c` stored at `5`.  This way you simply use your input numbers as indices into this table.  You could use this lookup table with a vector; for example:

```
myNumbers = [ 1 3 3 1 5 ];
myLetters = numToLetter(myNumbers)
```

Gives the output:

```
myLetters =

abbac
```

Comment: I just noticed that you do the conversion here at `numToLetter(B{i}(j)` .. But can you please explain how this is working ?? I would love to understand this and learn rather than just copy.

Comment: Also, why do you have spaced in `numToLetter = [ 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c' ];` between letters ?? Why not `numToLetter=['a','b','c']` ?

Comment: I have tried this on the same cell but adding a few zeros such as `1 becomes 100` and `3 becomes 300` etc... I get this error : `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` Why ?

Comment: Look carefully at the bottom part of my answer, this should explain your question.  The reason I left spaces is because they were in positions 2 and 4, which you are not using.  I *needed* 'a', 'b' and 'c' to be in positions 1, 3, and 5 respectively in the `numToLetter` array, because the number you want to convert is the index into the array.  Once you understand that I am using the query number as an index into the `numToLetter` array, you should understand how to modify it.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh so the code only accounts for those specific numbers then (`1 3 5`)  ? I would rather have something that can adapt to any number, such as 100 300 or 500 (along with any other numbers) .. Any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: Well, presumably you still need to decide in advance which letter corresponds to which number?  So it would still be possible to create a vector which has the appropriate letter mappings for different numbers.  If the numbers get too large however you will end up with a huge array with gaps in it.  You should look at the `containers.Map` if this is the case.